# Проблемы с кодировкой страницы

Tags: кодировка, php

В общем имеется страница, но вместо текста отображается ���������. Подскажите, как исправить?

Привожу код верхней части (до закрытия тега head)

```
<?php include 'include/config.php';?>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $siteLink;?>/jQuery/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $siteLink;?>/jQuery/jquery.lavalamp.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#1, #2, #3").lavaLamp({
                fx: "backout",
                speed: 800,
            });
        });
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Восток Строй</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $siteLink; ?>/style.css">
</head>
```

Comment: @Алексей Демиховский, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если открыть через Notepad++ то там есть вкладка `Кодировки` можно просто выбрать `Кодировать в UTF-8`, ну и пере сохранить файл. Мне помогло

Comment: Этот метод работает далеко не всегда, к сожалению...

Comment: К сожалению да.

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value default_charset utf-8
php_value default_charset utf-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Прямо под `<head>`, вставьте

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

, и еще не помещает в самое начало страницы добавить такой PHP код:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

и уберите строчку

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

, так как старые браузеры ее не понимают, такие как Internet Explorer 6 и ему подобные.

Answer (score -1):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Что касается Вашего скрипта php, достаточно перевести файл в кодировку utf-8 без bom/utf-8 в зависимости от операционной системы на которой установлен PHP(windows/unix) соответственно. На основании кодировки файла PHP проинформирует браузер о кодировке в заголовках HTTP пакета

Определение кодировки страницы браузерами происходит приблизительно следующим образом:

1. Пользователь в настройках браузера явно указал кодировку, в этом случае остальные пункты не рассматриваются
2. Кодировка берется из заголовков HTTP пакета (если пользователь не указал ее явно в настройках браузера)
3. Если браузер определил что кодировка из второго пункта не соответствует правильной, кодировка берется из тэга <meta>
4. Во всех пунктах выше кодировка не верная, некоторые браузеры могут попытаться сами определить верный вариант.

Что касается вашего случая, можно изменить в файл php.ini директиву отвечающую за кодировку передаваемых файлов, но этот пункт мне кажется не совсем правильным так как у Вас не всегда на это может хватить прав, и на одном сервере может находиться множество сайтов с разными кодировками.

Что касается ответов про СУБД. Из примера приведенного в вопросе нет никакого обращения в БД. Кодировку БД следует рассматривать только если кодировка нарушена в тексте который выводится из БД. В СУБД есть кодировка соединения, кодировка БД, таблиц и полей. Это отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Я так понимаю, что не в правильной кодировке записи из БД идут. Поэтому добавте в include/config.php после подключения к БД:

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
```